# Aligning a Navigation Menu with a logo

Tags: css, alignment, css-float, vertical-alignment

I might having some understanding problems with basic CSS but, even by looking on other threads I just cannot get rid of that problem.
I've realized that vertical-align just works on inline elements, which is fine. But some problems come out when I actually try to vertically align a menu to the left of its logo.
I still think this issue is caused by floating elements and position property, which are a huge understanding problem for me but I hope someone can just help me to deal with this, because it's starting to be a bit annoying.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png"
  </div>
  <div id="nav-container">
    <ul id="navbar">
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
   </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding; 0;
}
#container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
}
#nav-container {
  margin: 0;
  width: 750px;
  float: right;
  border:1px black dashed;
  height: 200px;
}
ul#navbar {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul#navbar > li {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
ul#navbar > li > a {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px black solid;
}
ul#navbar > li > a:hover {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}
ul#navbar > li > a > p{
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

My pen:
http://codepen.io/Rej/pen/egKYEa

Comment: do you want to align the logo to the menu items or to the container `#nav-container`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is some modifications should be made to the HTML and CSS

1- the image tag `img` not closed etc missing `/>`

2- the elements that need floating in the navigation is the `li`s not `a`s
so i changed it in the css.

3- logo container is `div` tag which is inline tag so I added `display:inline-block`

4- the logo image is containing empty white space which make it not appropriate for testing I replace it via [placeholder](http://placehold.it)

5- to align the menu you can use sudo element `after` and `vertical-align:middle`

check the demo below

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding; 0;
}
#container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
}
#nav-container {
  margin: 0;
  width: 750px;
  float: right;
  border:1px black dashed;
  height: 200px;
}
ul#navbar {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul#navbar:after{
  content:'';
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
ul#navbar > li {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  float: left;
  
}
ul#navbar > li > a {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px black solid;
}
ul#navbar > li > a:hover {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}
ul#navbar > li > a > p{
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
#logo{
  display:inline-block;
}
div#nav-container:after {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200"/>
    </div>
    <div id="nav-container">
      <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
  </div>
 
      </div>
</body>
```

Please leave a feedback if I miss-understand your question

Comment: Well, i didn't know about the placeholder thing but I guess I've discovered a new thing thanks to you!
Anyways, I've ran the code snippet you provided me but I think I might have been a bit misleading with the explanation. I actually require the menu itself to be vertically-aligned to the logo.
i.e. 200px header with a 200px height logo. My menu should be right at the middle height between the logo baseline and the logo upperline. I just don't really know how to achieve that.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!! But what does `content: ' ';` actually do in that situation? I mean, what is that empty space for?

Comment: sudo elements should have `content` property in order to be rendered on the page in case we don't want certain content, simply put an empty string in the value NOT space just `content:'';`

Answer (score 0):

hope that will help you ,I pratically changed the image position to  be after the list as you want
Here is some css fits your code needs:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding; 0;
}
#container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
}
#nav-container {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  border:1px black dashed;
  height: 200px;
}

ul#navbar {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul#navbar > li {

  vertical-align: bottom;
}
ul#navbar > li > a {
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
ul#navbar > li > a:hover {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}
ul#navbar > li > a > p{
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

and you have some html problems so after correcting them it looks like :

```
<div id="container">

  <div id="nav-container">
    <ul id="navbar">
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
     <div id="logo">
    <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png">
  </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: That was not really my request! I actually like the position of the elements itself! I just need the menu to be correctly vertical-aligned to the header